# stop android animated button from looping?

Tags: android, xml

In Android, I've created an animated button by referencing the below XML in the button_pressed.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_on_1" android:duration="30" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_on_2" android:duration="30" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_on_3" android:duration="30" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_on_4" android:duration="30" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_on_5" android:duration="30" />

</animation-list>
```

It works fine, but if you hold the button down (keep it pressed) the animation loops. Is there an XML call I can put in the above XML to keep the animation from looping? To make it run through the animation only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call the animation on button click(using onClickListener()) instead.. this will start your animation only if the user performs a full click action on the button (press + release).

**EDIT:**

```
yourButtonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /* start the animation here */

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Cata. I'm now to android, how would I write that into the onClickListener?